# sqlite file is empty when send it via MFMailcomposeController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data

I want to send the coreData sqlite file via mail

```
NSURL *appDoc = [[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject];
NSURL *storeURL = [appDoc URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"Log.sqlite"];
NSData *sqliteData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfURL:storeURL];
MFMailComposeViewController * mailComposeVC = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
[mailComposeVC addAttachmentData:sqliteData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"Log.sqlite"];
```

All data exists in DB, I can see it by call `executeFetchRequest` on `NSManagedObjectContext`

But, the file is empty.

I try to insert 10,000 rows for testing.
and after that the file include 9775 rows only.

Why?

Comment: You probably need to ensure the database is closed before sending it.  It's a bad idea anyway; if you want to exchange data then use an interchange file format like JSON.

Comment: Thanks,
1. How can cloדe the DB?
2. why it's bad idea? I want to get DB file for filter data easily.

Comment: Not sure with coredata TBH.

Comment: @zeevblu, did u found any solution for this? I am also facing the same issue.