# Found empty data in sqlite when send via MFMailcomposeController

Tags: ios, objective-c, sqlite, core-data, mfmailcomposeviewcontroller

I am sending **SQLite(Coredata sqlite file)** file via email but found empty data in all tables in the received mail.

I am using below code:

```
MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
[mc setSubject:subject];
[mc setMessageBody:body isHTML:FALSE];
if (attachmentData) {
 [mc addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:fileMimeType fileName:fileName];
}
if (!recipients || recipients.count == 0) {
 recipients = @[];
}
[mc setToRecipients:recipients];
[presentedViewController presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

> Here, fileMimeType = "application/x-sqlite3" and fileName: xyz.sqlite

Found the same [question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/26833013/1635315) here, but with no solution. Any idea how to do that?

Comment: Are you sending just the .sqlite file?  iOS uses WAL mode by default, so you will need to send the WAL file as well.

Comment: Yeah, I am sending SQLite file only. Let me send WAL file and check.

Comment: Great! using WAL file it works. Got all the data. Thanks, @pbasdf. Plz, post your answer below so I can accept.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I indicated in comments, iOS uses SQLite’s WAL mode by default, so you need to include the WAL file as an attachment.

Answer (score 0):

- Are you sure that you attachmentData isn't nil?
- How large is your attachmentData?
- How are you constructing your data from the sqlite file?

This test code seemed to work fine for me with sending a simple sample database:

```
- (void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated {
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self sendSampleMailWithDbAttached];
}

- (void)sendSampleMailWithDbAttached {
    MFMailComposeViewController *mc = [[MFMailComposeViewController alloc] init];
    mc.mailComposeDelegate = self;
    [mc setSubject:@"Message Subject"];
    [mc setMessageBody:@"Message Body" isHTML:NO];
    NSString *sqliteFilePath = [self createTestDb];
    NSData *attachmentData = [NSData dataWithContentsOfFile:sqliteFilePath];
    if (attachmentData) {
        [mc addAttachmentData:attachmentData mimeType:@"application/x-sqlite3" fileName:@"xyz.sqlite"];
    }
    [mc setToRecipients:@[@"fake@email.com"]];
    [self presentViewController:mc animated:YES completion:nil];
}

- (NSString *)createTestDb {
    NSString *databasePath = [[NSSearchPathForDirectoriesInDomains(NSDocumentDirectory, NSUserDomainMask, YES) objectAtIndex:0]
                              stringByAppendingPathComponent: @"xyz.sqlite"];
    sqlite3 *db;
    if (sqlite3_open([databasePath UTF8String], &db) == SQLITE_OK) {
        NSString *query = @"CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS test(abc TEXT, def TEXT);";
        if (sqlite3_exec(db, [query UTF8String], NULL, NULL, NULL) == SQLITE_OK) {
            query = @"INSERT INTO test(abc, def) VALUES('ABC', '123');";
        }
        sqlite3_close(db);
    }
    return databasePath;
}
```

Comment: Yes, 1) DB file isn't nil, 2) attachmentData length is : actaul is 238KB but while Fetching using 3rd point found 160 KB 3) NSURL *sqliteURL = [[[[NSFileManager defaultManager] URLsForDirectory:NSDocumentDirectory inDomains:NSUserDomainMask] lastObject] URLByAppendingPathComponent:@"xyz.sqlite"]

Comment: I am using Coredata.

Comment: I tried your code, but it is working fine with SQLite DB but not with Coredata.